# Converting var to float for math operation

Tags: ios, function, swift, math

I'm coding a simple application with xcode using swift. I'd create a function the calculate the BMR but there are some problems here. How can I fix'em? This is my code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {     
    @IBOutlet var Age: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Height: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Weight: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var agefield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var heightfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var weightfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var BMR: UILabel!
    @IBAction func Calculate(sender: UIButton) {
        var a = "66,0"
        var b = "13,7"
        var c = (weightfield.text as NSString).floatValue
        var d = "5,0"
        var e = (heightfield.text as NSString).floatValue
        var f = "6,8"
        var g = (agefield.text as NSString).floatValue
        var result = a + (b * c) + (d * e) - (f * g)
        BMR.text = "\(result)"

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

**c, e and g value depend from a text field**
There's an error on the "var result" row: "Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments"
Then, I've created a playground and I changed the c, e and g variables with real number and it works!

```
var a = 66.0
var b = 13.7
var c = 72.0
var d = 5.0
var e = 178.0
var f = 6.8
var g = 16.0

var result = a + (b * c) + (d * e) - (f * g)

print(result)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

--

```
let a:Float = 66.0
let b:Float = 13.7
var c = (weightfield.text as NSString).floatValue
let d:Float = 5.0
var e = (heightfield.text as NSString).floatValue
let f:Float = 6.8
var g = (agefield.text as NSString).floatValue
var result = a + (b * c) + (d * e) - (f * g)
BMR.text = "\(result)"
```

Hexagon, thank for your precious help. This is the changed code. There are no issues :D ...but there's SIGABRT signal so the App can't run. Where's the error?

--

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Calculator.ViewController 0x7fcf28467e20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key BMI.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109f77c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bae2bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109f778a9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010a395b53 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109ebfd50 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010aaee52b -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010a946718 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010a946d08 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010a946f79 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010a94740e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010a8622c9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010a86268f -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010a86ee21 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010a812457 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2732
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010a8151de -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010a8140d5 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d5f25e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109eab41c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109ea1165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109ea0947 __CFRunLoopRun + 887
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109ea0366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010a813b42 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010a816900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  Calculator                          0x0000000109d6dcd7 main + 135
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c23a145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: In your ViewController your values are *strings*. You have to convert these to *floats*, like you did in the Playground, before being able to do maths on them. Search SO there's many examples of how to do that.

Comment: reg. SIGABRT ... your code looks good now. I recommend to do a clean and compile again. If an error is thrown while running your app check the console for error information.

Comment: Hexagon, it finally works! You have been precious for me. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to multiply/add `String` values with `Float` values. Additionally, if you would leave your literal numbers untyped, they would be `Double`s which, again don't mix with `Float`s without a cast. Here's what would work for example:

```
@IBAction func Calculate(sender: UIButton) {
    var a:Float = 66.0
    var b:Float = 13.7
    var c = (weightfield.text as NSString).floatValue
    var d:Float = 5.0
    var e = (heightfield.text as NSString).floatValue
    var f:Float = 6.8
    var g = (agefield.text as NSString).floatValue
    var result = a + (b * c) + (d * e) - (f * g)
    BMR.text = "\(result)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks hexagon, but I didn't understand: a, b, d, and f values are constants in my function but c, e and g values depends on a value that you type into text field (they are variables). Would Float/Double values change something? Would Float/Double values fix, for example, the c, e and g values (they should change according to the values that you type into text fields)?

Comment: No, you had your constant values above defined as `String`s and you can't use math operations between strings and numbers. Since you're using floating point numbers you need to define them either as `Float`s or as `Double`s but you probably won't need Double precision so you can define them all as Floats. Btw if your literal numbers (a, b, d, f) should be constant it's best to define them with `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: Hex, I've just edited the main answer, could you check? (I've just started sculpting your statue, you have been so useful: I'm noob)